# Can't run C/C++ programs that use standard library

Tags: command-line, c++

I was trying to remove the [Openfst](http://openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/WebHome) library from my system. However, using **make uninstall** didn't work. Hence I tried to search for files that contain `fst` in **/usr/** directory and deleted them with the following command:

```
sudo find . -name '*fst*' -delete
```

Unfortunately, that also deleted some standard library files such as `fstream`

And now, I cannot run any C/C++ programs that use `fstream`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it was `-name '\*fst*'` and not `-name '*/fst*'`? What directory were you in when you executed it?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the directory. Also, it is `-name '*fst*'`. The _/_ was typo error

Comment: I'd start by trying something like `dpkg -S '*fst*' | while IFS=: read -r pkg file; do [[ -e "${file# }" ]] || echo "$pkg: $file"; done` to create a list of all the packages that think they own files matching `'*fst*` and which files are missing